# Easy styling of all Td's in a table or in a div

Tags: html, css, html-table

Is there a way I can use one category to stylize all of my table cells? I cant just use

```
td{

}
```

because I have another table on the same page that I don't want the same style on. The table I want to stylize has around 40 cells, so is there a way to collectively style them short of copy-pasting a class or id 40 times?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Put a selector on the table tag:

```
<table class="my-special-table">
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>

table.my-special-table td { /*style it up!*/ }
```

Answer (score 13):

If your table has a specific attribute such an as ID, you can reference it in CSS specifically:

```
<table id="myStyledTable">
    <tr>
        <td>...
```

Like so:

```
#myStyledTable td {

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
#table-id td {
 /* some css */ 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or 
    #table-id > tr > td { /* some css */ }
in case you will have other tables within this table that shouldn't have this style applied.

Answer (score 1):

You can give an id/class to that table and do :

```
#yourtable td { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either an id or a class will allow it to be individually styled as:

```
<table class="myclass">
```

or

```
<table id="myid">
```

and then

```
.myclass td {}
```

or

```
#myid td {}
```

respectively.